# how to use embedded expression with classpath

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass the absolute value of a file to the read function for classpath.

If I pass absolute path along with classpath it works fine. But when I pass embedded expression its not working

My code is as below

```
Scenario: create swagger first RAD
```

Given url appServer
Given param creationMethod = 'SWAGGER_FIRST'
And path '/integration/rest/rad'

And header X-CSRF-TOKEN = csrfToken
* cookie JSESSIONID = jsessionid
* cookie route = routevalue
* configure charset = null

- print swaggerDetailsinputFile
- print swaggerInputJsonFile
  Given multipart file inputData = { read: 'classpath: #(swaggerDetailsinputFile)', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
  Given multipart file swaggerFile = { read: 'classpath:ic/feature/RAD/swagger.json', filename: 'blob', contentType: 'application/json' }
  And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
  When method post

[image]

Need a way to pass embedded expression to classpath value for read function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
read: '#("classpath:" + swaggerDetailsinputFile)'
```

Make sure you read this part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: Thank you Peter for very quick and accurate response.