# Karate BDD passing parameter in URL

Tags: parameter-passing, karate

So I know how to pass a parameter in Karate.

- def portId ='#portId'
  And use this portId variable for parametrization.

But when I use this variable inside a URL like this
Given url myvesturl +'service/portfolio/' + portld

Then it is printing me #portId not the value I was providing in my other feature file.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental mis-understanding of karate variables, please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738181/143475 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52356667/143475 - so you can avoid that `def` step and it may just work. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1):

> Then it is printing me #portId not the value I was providing in my other feature file.

It doesn't have access to the other feature file (based on the code you have given) so this is correct.

In every feature you're trying to use the variable, you either need to `* def` the variable again, OR if you're doing `* def someTest = call read('myvestURL.feature') { portId: 'portId' }` This will [call](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call) the myvestURL.feature below

**myvesturl.feature**

```
  Feature: myvesturl feature

     Background: your background text
       * def yourEndPoint = 'http://url.com' + 'service/portfolio/' + portId
     Scenario: your scenario text
        Given url yourEndPoint
etc
```

If you need to use params, please refer to the [example](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#param) in the doc as karate handles that